# NestJS : Updated cookies from backend endpoint not affecting NestJS middleware response

Tags: typescript, express, cookies, nestjs, middleware

I'm running into an issue with my middleware setup in NestJs for my API. Initially, I've got cookies handling JWTs, and that part works just fine. Recently, I tried setting up a '/refresh' endpoint to create a new access token and update the client's cookie with this fresh token once the old one has expired or is close to expiring:

```
@UseGuards(JwtRefreshGuard)
@Get('/refresh')
refresh(@Req() request: RequestWithUser) {
  try {
    console.log('entering refresh try');
    const accessTokenCookie = this.authService.getCookieWithJwtAccessToken(request.user.id);
    request.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', accessTokenCookie);
    console.log('new cookie =', accessTokenCookie);
    return request.user;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

(The guard only checks if the user has a refresh token and if it matches the one stored in the database etc.)

For this purpose, I wanted to create a middleware that would check the access token's expiration time for each request:

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { UserService } from './user/user.service';
import RequestWithUser from './interfaces/requestWithUser.interface';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class isAuthenticated implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService, private readonly userService: UserService) {}
    async use(req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        try {
            const accessToken = req.cookies.Authentication;
            if (accessToken) {
                const decodedToken = this.jwtService.decode(accessToken) as { [key: string]: any } | null;
                // token will expire in less than 10 min
                if (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) >= decodedToken.exp - 600)
                {
                    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/auth/refresh', {
                    headers: {
                        Cookie: `Refresh=${req.cookies.Refresh}`,
                    },
                    });
                }
                else
                    console.log('token ok');
                next();
            }
            else { 
                // no access token found, we check if there is a refresh token
                const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/auth/refresh', {
                    headers: {
                        Cookie: `Refresh=${req.cookies.Refresh}`,
                    },
                });
            next();
          }
        } catch(error: any){
            throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the action taken in the '/refresh' endpoint to set the cookie (request.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', accessTokenCookie)) doesn't seem to affect the actual cookies owned by the client. The access token remains unchanged in the browser console.

I've found a workaround by directly setting the cookie in the middleware itself, but I'm perplexed about why it's necessary. It seems like I'm missing a key detail or two.

Even though the call to '/refresh' works, and I can see the right 'Set-Cookie' header in the response received by my middleware, it's puzzling why this doesn't reflect in the actual client-side cookies.

```
 'set-cookie': [
  'Authentication=xxxx'
    ],
```

Basically, if I manually trigger the call to my endpoint through the address bar, it works. But when the call is made by the middleware, cookies are not updated.

Why does the Set-Cookie action performed in /refresh seems to have no effect when called by my middleware ? Is the request updated at that point different from the one handled and returned by the middleware? Is what I'm trying to do impossible without executing Set-Cookie in the middleware directly? Or am I missing something ?

Additional Details:

- NestJs version: 10.2.1
- app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModule.register({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './public',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
          cb(null, `${uuidv4()}-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
      }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({...DataSourceConfig, entities: [User, Message]}),
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
    FormAuthModule,
    ChatModule,
    HttpModule
],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [JwtService, JwtRefreshTokenStrategy],
})
export class AppModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(isAuthenticated)
            .forRoutes('/user', '/chat', '/auth/logout');
    }
}
```

- main.ts :

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import * as cors from 'cors';


async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
        transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion : true,
        }
    }))

    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    }));  
    
    await app.listen(4000);
    }
    bootstrap();
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me out :-)